# The asset "devise/sessions.css" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying configure the devise gem on my application built in Rails 5.2.

After install devise and create the views I'm get this error

```
The asset "devise/sessions.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.

 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    params[:controller], media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller], 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

That was raised on line #9.

I've already created this file on my app/assets folder and setted on my assets.rb file like this:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( addresses.css
                                                  welcome.css
                                                  donations.css
                                                  givers.css
                                                  sessions.css
                                                  scaffolds.css)
```

and this:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( addresses.css
                                                  welcome.css
                                                  donations.css
                                                  givers.css
                                                  devise/sessions.css
                                                  scaffolds.css)
```

But I continue receiving the same error.

I have no more ideias what to do to solve my problem, someone could help me, please?

Comment: Have you created the file in folder app/assets/stylesheets/devise ?

Comment: Yes,@Maxence. The name of my view is Admin, so I also tried to create the file in the folder app/assets/stylesheets/admim and app/assets/stylesheets/admins too . But I had no success.

Comment: The app is trying to find it in stylesheets/devise folder. If it is there it should be ok. Have you tried restarting the server ?